# return only sequentially numbered values from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql query using the listagg function to create a comma separated list into one returned field which is working correctly.  But I'd like to only include results where the sequentially ordered results have sequence numbers that are sequential.  They must all start with 0, but there is no specific end sequence number.  They sometimes skip a sequence number, so I want to remove those

so for example, I want to include values that look like this

```
0
0,1
0,1,2
0,1,2,3
```

but I want to skip results that look like

```
1
0,2
0,1,3
0,0,2
```

is there some SQL syntax that would filter values out like this?

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) show the query you are using and (2) show sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this with a `having` clause:

```
select listagg(col, ',') . . .
from t
group by . . .
having min(col) = 0 and
       count(*) = count(distinct col) and
       max(col) = count(*) - 1
```

These conditions should ensure that rows with non-sequential values are filtered out.

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of most of the issues, but I just realized that we have cases of duplicate sequence numbers.  I just added that to the examples.  I think the suggested code might confuse 0,0,2 as an acceptable result in this case.

Comment: @Jonjilla . . . No it won't.  These conditions take that into account.

Comment: I see.  I didn't notice the distinct.  Thanks!